# Can't click on buttons after CSS transform

Tags: html, css, transform

I'm trying to make a html page with a cube on it, each face of said cube would have buttons on it. On the default face all the buttons work fine, however, as soon as I rotate the cube the new face looses all interactivity.

HTML:

```
<button type="button" id="button">Toggle</button>
<hr>
<div id="cube">
    <div class="face one"></div>
    <div class="face two">
        <button type="button">All</button>
        <button type="button">News</button>
        <button type="button">Media</button>
        <button type="button">Events</button>
    </div>
    <div class="face three"></div>
    <div class="face four"></div>
    <div class="face five">
        <button type="button">All</button>
        <button type="button">News</button>
        <button type="button">Media</button>
        <button type="button">Events</button>
    </div>
    <div class="face six"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#cube {
    position: relative;
    height: 400px;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 2s linear;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.face {
    position: absolute;
    height: 360px;
    background-color:#ffffff;
}
#cube .one {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(200px);
}
#cube .two {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(200px);
}
#cube .three {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(200px);
}
#cube .four {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(200px);
}
#cube .five {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(200px);
}
#cube .six {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(200px) rotate(180deg);
}
```

And JS:

```
$("#button").click(function () {
    $('#cube').css("-webkit-transform", "rotateX(0deg) rotateY(90deg)");
});
```

Here's a Fiddle link demonstrating my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/x66yn/

(Note that the demo will only work on webkit browsers.)

Comment: You rotating the button with 90deg in this case button is positioning with backside that's why button is not clicked.

Comment: @Tukhsanov Actually for the buttons to be behind the cube then it would have to apply a -90 rotation on the Y axis, perhaps it's easier to notice on this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x66yn/9/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to give the elements a non-static `position`. This is because the elements are not currently positioned in their parent, with the parent being moved forward it covers the children

```
button {
    position: relative; /* Or absolute, fixed */
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/x66yn/13/)

Note: I added a cursor change on hover to show it works

The other option is to move the buttons forward in the Z direction greater than or equal to it's parent z-axis movement since you're doing so with the parent

```
button {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(200px); /* Equivalent or greater than parent's*/
    transform: translateZ(200px);
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/x66yn/10/)

In your case specifically, the back panel will not work just using the above, the angle of the right button also cannot be 90 (some some reason which I don't know for sure). It has to do with how the browser is rendering it. As a result, just use 89.999 which is indistinguishable to us but works fine

```
$("#buttonRight").click(function () {
    $('#cube').css("-webkit-transform", "rotateX(0deg) rotateY(89.999deg)");
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but on your demos I'm still not able to click the buttons on Face Five (after Toggle Right).

Comment: That's odd about the `90deg ` issue.Wonder why it does that.

Answer (score 3):

I had similar problem, but for me help remove from cube(DIV) this ruls: `backface-visibility : hidden;` and rotate cube by 89.99 (just two "9" after dot)

With this cube work in Chrome, Firefox, Safari and IE11

Comment: In my case, setting `backface-visibility: hidden;` was all that was needed. I could still use `rotate: 90deg;` without any problems after that.