# Calling AngularJs function after css rotation

Tags: angularjs, css, transform

I have a button that rotates on click for confirmation.
http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/21763/

```
.flip-button-wrapper.selected .button-flipper{
   transform: rotateX(-90deg);
}
```

Initial click works fine, but after rotation, function is not being called.

Not sure if this is css issue of angular.

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know it's super weird and I can't seem to find anything that explains it as it seems like a bug in CSS, but for some reason when rotating 90 degrees, this seems to occur. I'll try to find other reasons but at least for now try:

```
.flip-button-wrapper.selected .button-flipper{
    transform: rotateX(-89.99deg);
}
```

It'll render the same but it'll allow you to click and toggle between rotating up and down.

Comment: It's linked to the position of the element (z-index i guess). When you have a rotate 90 and inspect, you get the parent div, but when you rotate 89 you get the clickable span. So probably if you play around position and z-indexes you could make it work with 90deg aswell.

Comment: Nevermind, found out it doesn't seem to be any work around -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23548612/cant-click-on-buttons-after-css-transform